# Removing php array duplicates with regard to a few specific indexes

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have a multi-dimensional array with 100's of sub-arrays.  The sub-arrays always have at least 3 indexes, but can have more.  I'd like to remove from the big array all the sub-arrays which are duplicates of others *in regards to those three indexes*.  Example with an array that only has two sub-arrays:

```
array(array(0 => 'a', 1=> 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd'), array(0 => 'a', 1=> 'b', 2=> 'c', 3=> 'z'))
```

one of the sub-arrays would be removed, because the first 3 indexes match even though the 4th does not.

I'm looking for the most elegant/efficient solution.

Comment: So which one if the two would be removed?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Create Unique Arrays using an md5 hash
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
function arrayUnique($array, $preserveKeys = false)
{
    $arrayRewrite = array();
    $arrayHashes = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $item) {
        $hash = md5(serialize($item));
        if (!isset($arrayHashes[$hash])) {
            $arrayHashes[$hash] = $hash;
            if ($preserveKeys) {
                $arrayRewrite[$key] = $item;
            } else {
                $arrayRewrite[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    return $arrayRewrite;
}

$uniqueArray = arrayUnique($array);
var_dump($uniqueArray);
```

FROM: http://www.phpdevblog.net/2009/01/using-array-unique-with-multidimensional-arrays.html

Removed comments to give people incentive to visit site - I've used this on a few occasions.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: although not a solution to this particular problem in that you require matching the first 3 indexes, it is still nontheless a very good solution to the general question: how do I use array_unique() on a multidimensional array.

If somebody could pop along and edit for your purposes, all the better!

Comment: K, ill modify it myself.  Why doesn't PHP have a function like array_unique_custom(compare_callback,array).  where you could provide the callback which the diffferent indexes would be compared on?

Comment: This example can be improved in several ways, but there is a major mistake as well: due to the `md5` call, you cannot _guarantee_ that this function will behave correctly unless you know beforehand all the possible permutations of types and values for both keys and items in the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Zenph gets it 90% right, but he wanted to only look at the first 3 elements as unique.  You can use the function below in conjunction with Zenph's code right before the serialize to only look at the first three elements.

```
function firstThree($array)
{
   $retArray = array();
   array_push($retArray, $array[1], $array[2], $array[3]);
   return $retArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Not the most elegant example due to the free function with a static variable, but you can make it more elegant by using a lambda or an instance of a class for the callback target.

```
function filter($subArray) {
    static $seenKeys = null;
    if ($seenKeys === null) {
        $seekKeys = array();
    }

    // I 'm just selecting the "three first" indexes here,
    // you can change it to better suit your needs
    $thisKey = serialize(array_slice($subArray, 0, 3));
    if (isset($seenKeys[$thisKey])) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return $seenKeys[$thisKey] = true;
    }
}

$result = array_filter($inputArray, 'filter');
```

I think this example is as fast as you can go in PHP without making assumptions about the type and/or values of the first three items in each subarray. If any such assumption can be made, then at the very least the `serialize` call can be replaced with something more appropriate. I imagine that this would speed up the process quite a bit.